# plot the probability distribution function of set of data in julia

Tags: julia

I have a set of data in matrix columns, I want to plot PDF, CDF and ect. of each column in julia. what can i do?
I use this

```
a=maximum(porosity)
b=minimum(porosity)
xs1=a:0.001:b
Plots.plot(xs1, pdf(porosity, xs), legend=nothing)
```

but

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching pdf(::Matrix{Float64}, ::StepRangeLen{Float64, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Int64}).
```

porosity is n*1 matrix

Answer (score 3):

If you want to plot KDE of PDF use `density` from StatsPlots.jl.

If you want to plot ECDF use `ecdfplot` from StatsPlots.jl.

```
using StatsPlots
density(porosity) # plot KDE of PDF
p = ecdfplot(porosity[:, 1]); # ECDF of first column
foreach(i -> ecdfplot!(p, porosity[:, i]), 2:size(porosity, 2)); # add the rest of ECDFs
p # display
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to add some explanations, i said that there is a set of data, i have to write the statistics parameters code as my H.W. in julia (I started few time ago). i want to check the skewness of data as a plotted figure, so i want to plot the frequency of data, and then calculate PDF CDF and ect. I don't know how can i plot frequency

Comment: Or its better that i asked you, how can i use pdf function for data which stored as a matrix?

Comment: You cannot, by definition. The `pdf` function works on continuous distributions. Therefore I showed you how to plot a kernel density estimator of PDF using a sample of data.